# How can I stream/chunk database results asynchronously?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'd like to use an `Enumerator` (similar to the [ScalaStream](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaStream) example) to chunk database results to the response as TSV. I may have many thousands of rows and i don't want to page the results nor do i want to accumulate the entire `ResultSet` into a single `String`. If needed, it is ok for chunks to not break at line separators. In other words, the only criteria is to chunk the results, not that it adhere to TSV delimiters.

I'd like to do something like this in my Action:

```
Ok.stream(new Iterator[ResultSet] {
  val conn = DB.getConnection()
  val stmt = conn.createStatement
  val rs = stmt.executeQuery("""select * from atable""")
  def hasNext = !rs.isLast() && !rs.isClosed()
  def next() = {
    if (!rs.next()) {
      conn.close()
      null
    } else rs
  }
}.toStream)
```

Unfortunately, the `Ok.stream` expects a `java.io.InputStream` and going the route of wrapping the results in an `InputStream` seems excessive. `Ok.stream` also accepts an `Enumerator` but i'm not sure how to create one in this context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, you can't do it "asynchronously", because the JDBC API is synchronous - when you call `rs.next()`, it will block synchronously.  But that's ok, just need to make sure your thread pools are tuned to allow blocking operations (ie, make them large).  Play has an asynchronous streaming API (which is quite different to the synchronous InputStream/OutputStream that you're most likely used to), that uses things called iteratees/enumerators.  You want to create an enumerator that enumerates your ResultSet.  Essentially, you want to do something that looks like this:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

val conn = DB.getConnection()
val stmt = conn.createStatement
val resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("""select * from atable""")

Ok.stream(Enumerator.unfold(resultSet) { (rs: ResultSet) =>
  if (rs.next()) {
    val chunk = // Read the result from the ResultSet and format it in the way you want it formatted
    Some((rs, chunk))
  } else None
}.onDoneEnumerating {
  resultSet.close()
  stmt.close()
  conn.close()
})
```

Comment: Perfect! By asynchronous, i was thinking i can perform the entire request, start to finish, i.e. all chunks, in futures. This terminology is probably way off but something like an Iteratee of Futures of Chunks. At any rate, **that solutions works brilliantly**. Thanks! And now i just need to understand it's impact. If i have 100 simultaneous of these requests, how is the server handling the responses? More endless learning ... :)

Comment: While you could use Enumerator.unfoldM to return futures, the best you can do with ResultSet is wrap its calls in Future, which doesn't make it asynchronous, at best it just changes which thread pool is used to do the synchronous operations. And you don't need to do this anyway, under the covers all these calls get wrapped in future and delegated to the implicit ExecutionContext accepted by unfold.

Comment: As for what happens with 100 requests, you will have up to the threadpool limits calling ResultSet.next, but at the same time any client that is slow at reading won't hold anything up because the sending of data is asynchronous. But note that all that is dependent on your database connection pool sizes, if you have 10 connections in your connection pool, only 10 concurrent downloads will be possible. This is a problem with traditional databases and these sorts of use cases, they don't handle it very well.